# Is there a way to find customized permissions in TFS

Tags: tfs

We are planning to move our Team Foundation Server server to a new domain, and as such any customized permissions will need to be updated/corrected.
I was wondering if there was a tool, or some sample code I could use to scan through TFS files and folders (as seen in Source Control Explorer) to find permissions that are different from the default.
Note that unfortunately, we are still using TFS 2010.
What I would like is to get or build a summarized list saying at this path, security was changed for User X to a, User Y to b, etc. and if inheritance was turned off.  If a path did not have any security changes, then I would prefer it if it is not included in the report.  I can build code to strip that out if necessary as long as the report is in an editable format (e.g. csv, xml, html, txt)

I am quite willing to create the tool myself, I am just unsure where to start.  It seems like the libraries for this are so large and often these things are not well documented.  If I create this, I will share what I can.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing code to do this.  I'm sorry it took so long to post this.
It creates a text file that specifies the security on every item in TFS that has explicit security.  It may give more information that needed, but worked well for my needs.
If you make use of this, you should replace "TFSServer" with your actual server name, and "CollectionName" with the actual source code collection name which is typically "DefaultCollection".

Note that this was written in VB, and requires the following references.

> Default references of System, System.Core, XML, and XML.Linq are included.
> <sub>From "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0"</sub>
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
Imports Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client
Imports Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client
Imports System.IO

Namespace EnumerateTFSSecurity
    Friend Class Program
        Private Shared UpdateConsoleIndex As Integer

        Shared Sub Main()
            Try
                Dim tfs As TfsTeamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(New Uri("http://TFSServer:8080/tfs/CollectionName"))
                Dim OutputFileName As String = ".\EnumTFSSec.txt"

                If Command().Length <> 0 Then
                    OutputFileName = Command()
                End If

                tfs.EnsureAuthenticated()

                Dim VersionControl As VersionControlServer = tfs.GetService(Of VersionControlServer)()

                Dim OutputFile As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(OutputFileName)
                Dim AllProjs() As TeamProject = VersionControl.GetAllTeamProjects(True)

                For Each TeamProj As TeamProject In AllProjs
                    GetChildItems(VersionControl, TeamProj.ServerItem, OutputFile)

                    OutputFile.Flush()
                Next

            Catch e As Exception
                Dim ex As String = e.Message
                Console.WriteLine("!!EXCEPTION: " & e.Message)
                Console.WriteLine("Continuing... ")
            End Try

            Console.WriteLine("========")
            Console.Read()
        End Sub

        Private Shared Sub GetChildItems(VersionControl As VersionControlServer, ItemPath As String, OutputFile As StreamWriter)
            Dim Items() As Item = VersionControl.GetItems(ItemPath & "/*").Items
            Dim FolderPaths As Specialized.StringCollection
            Dim FilePaths As List(Of String)

            FolderPaths = New Specialized.StringCollection
            FilePaths = New List(Of String)

            GetSecurityInfo(VersionControl, {ItemPath}, OutputFile)

            For Each Item As Item In Items
                If Item.ItemType = ItemType.Folder Then
                    FolderPaths.Add(Item.ServerItem)

                Else
                    FilePaths.Add(Item.ServerItem)
                End If
            Next

            For Each Folder As String In FolderPaths
                GetChildItems(VersionControl, Folder, OutputFile)
            Next

            If FilePaths.Count <> 0 Then
                GetSecurityInfo(VersionControl, FilePaths.ToArray, OutputFile)
            End If
        End Sub

        ' Define other methods and classes here
        Private Shared Sub GetSecurityInfo(VersionControl As VersionControlServer, ByVal ItemPaths() As String, OutputFile As StreamWriter)
            Dim result As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
            Dim SecurityList() As ItemSecurity
            Dim SecurityInfo As StringBuilder = Nothing
            Dim Clearstringlength As Integer
            Dim ConsoleText As String

            Try
                SecurityList = VersionControl.GetPermissions(ItemPaths, RecursionType.None)
                SecurityInfo = New StringBuilder

                If SecurityList IsNot Nothing AndAlso SecurityList.Length <> 0 Then
                    For Each ItemSecurity As ItemSecurity In SecurityList
                        With ItemSecurity
                            If .Inherit = False Then
                                SecurityInfo.Append(" - Inherit: False")
                            End If

                            For Each Entry As AccessEntry In .Entries
                                If (Entry.Allow.Length <> 0 OrElse Entry.Deny.Length <> 0) Then
                                    SecurityInfo.AppendLine()
                                    SecurityInfo.AppendLine("    Identity: " & Entry.IdentityName)

                                    If Entry.Allow.Length <> 0 Then
                                        SecurityInfo.Append("        Allow: ")

                                        For Each Value As String In Entry.Allow
                                            SecurityInfo.Append(Value & "; ")
                                        Next

                                        SecurityInfo.Remove(SecurityInfo.Length - 2, 2)

                                        If Entry.Deny.Length <> 0 Then
                                            SecurityInfo.AppendLine()
                                        End If
                                    End If

                                    If Entry.Deny.Length <> 0 Then
                                        SecurityInfo.Append("        Deny: ")

                                        For Each Value As String In Entry.Deny
                                            SecurityInfo.Append(Value & "; ")
                                        Next

                                        SecurityInfo.Remove(SecurityInfo.Length - 2, 2)
                                    End If
                                End If
                            Next

                            If SecurityInfo.Length <> 0 Then
                                SecurityInfo.AppendLine()
                            End If
                        End With

                        If UpdateConsoleIndex Mod 25 = 0 Then
                            ConsoleText = "Item:" & ItemSecurity.ServerItem
                            Clearstringlength = If(Console.CursorTop = 0, 0, Console.CursorTop * Console.BufferWidth - 1) - ConsoleText.Length
                            Console.CursorTop = 0
                            Console.CursorLeft = 0

                            If Clearstringlength > 0 Then
                                ConsoleText &= New String(" "c, Clearstringlength)
                            End If

                            Console.WriteLine(ConsoleText)
                        End If

                        If SecurityInfo IsNot Nothing AndAlso SecurityInfo.Length > 0 Then
                            If UpdateConsoleIndex <> 0 Then
                                OutputFile.WriteLine()
                            End If

                            OutputFile.Write("Item:" & ItemSecurity.ServerItem)

                            OutputFile.Write(SecurityInfo.ToString())

                            SecurityInfo.Clear()
                        End If

                        UpdateConsoleIndex += 1
                    Next
                End If

            Catch e As Exception
                Dim ex As String = e.Message
                Console.WriteLine("!!EXCEPTION: " & e.Message)
                Console.WriteLine("Continuing... ")
            End Try
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/). Team Foundation Sidekicks includes Permission Sidekick, which provides the following features:

- Select user whose effective permissions are to be reviewed
- View Team Foundation Server groups user is a member of (Windows
  domain groups are not included)
- View user's global TFS server permissions
- Select Team project to view project specific effective permissions
- View user's Team project's permissions
- Select project's version control folder/file and view effective
  version control permissions for that item (including indication
  whether permissions are inherited or explicitly set)
- Select project's area and view effective permissions for that area
- For every effective permissions display, view a reason for every
  effective permission setting - namely, for which groups Allow/Deny
  permissions are set and therefore what effective permission is based
  on

Comment: Sorry that I have been unable to check before as I have been busy working on many other things.  I was unsure at first which version to use because we program with Visual Studio 2019 and 2017, but we are currently using TFS 2010.  The documentation combines both so as to make it unclear which to use.  To be fair, this seems common for many TFS tools, and while some will work fine with the newer Visual Studio and older TFS, this one only partially does.  The one part I noticed is that not all permissions were read correctly with the newer versions.

Comment: I have just tried using this tool and it seems like it would be very time consuming to try to use it for my purpose and prone to errors.  While I can check individual users permissions of individual folders, it does not show when things like inheritance have been turned off.  I was really looking for something that I could get a summarized report from.  I am perfectly ok with building the code to read the security and create that summary, but I am unsure where to start as I have done almost no programming against TFS.

Comment: Since TFS 2010 is very old, you may check the old blogs to see whether they can help you: http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/09/30/tfs-sdk-get-groups-users-permissions-using-tfs-api-with.aspx.

Comment: Yes, I know.  I have tried looking through the documentation, but it is very difficult to find as everything wants to redirect to Azure DevOps/Azure DevOp Server 2019.  Also, the API reference for that appears to be broken/missing.  What little I have found so far has almost no descriptions or remarks to explain anything.  I just basically hope that the name is sufficiently descriptive which it isn't in many cases.

Comment: You may consider upgrading your TFS to modern versions.

Comment: We do plan to upgrade, but that is not something we can do right now.  I believe I have figured it out and plan to post that soon.

Comment: Hi @CeceDong. I finally was able to post my solution.  I hope it can help others.